# What is a Schrödinger background or a Schrödinger symmetry?

Tags: string-theory, symmetry

In some string theory paper, they mention "Schrödinger background" and "Schrödinger symmetry", which I never heard before.

What does that mean?

Comment: Which string theory paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Schrödinger background is a background with Schrödinger symmetry, and that, in turn, is having the [Schrödinger group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_group), which is the central extension of the Galileo group by the non-relativistic mass operator, as a symmetry group.

The relevance of the Schrödinger group in string theory and conformal field theory arises because the $d$-dimensional Schrödinger group embeds as a subgroup of the conformal group $\mathrm{SO}(2,d+2)$ in one dimension higher.